# Auto refactoring to string.Format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, automated-refactoring

I have a c# project in VS2008 that have a lot of lines of code that look like this:

```
string s = "bla blab" + x + "bla bla bla" + y + .... ;
```

and I would like to covert those strings to a single string using string.Format(...).

I am currently using Resharper 5.0, and I can refactor a single line of code with one click.
The problem is that I have more that a 1000 lines like this, and I don't want to manually go over each line.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Edit:
As Marc corrected me, I dont really need to do it,
but I have another very similar problem:
I got this code

```
 string s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                   "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                   "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                   "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                   "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                   "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                   "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
```

(the string is some sql query)

and I'd like to refactor it to one const string:

```
string s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....aaaaa";
```

(this time, it is more efficient, right?)

resharper can do this automatically per string,
but again, I'd like to do it a lot of times.

it would be great to keep the lines indentation:

```
string s = @"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
```

but just one long line is ok too.

thanks,
Lev.

Comment: Dave you tried regular expressions?

Comment: Out of curiosity; for what *benefit* do you want to do this?

Comment: @tjameson: I was hoping to do this without writing code. the last thing I want is that some random bug will some string some where.

@marc-gravell: it's much more efficient memory wise

Comment: Well, you can step through each one if you use the regex replace in VS2008.  That way you could verify that the replace is working, and you wouldn't have to do much but push Replace or Next...

Comment: @tjameson: No, you can’t. When you click Replace it instantly jumps to the next match. No opportunity to verify that the replace worked fine.

Comment: @Timwi Maybe he could run it on a single file or single instance.  If it works on a single instance, stepping through would allow him to avoid false positives.  If his lines are indeed similar, he wouldn't need to verify each one.  Otherwise he could just do a match, click, then he'd be done...

Comment: In that second version, the compiler does the concatenation of literals during compile. At runtime that is only one string. To repeat: it does not concatenate them at runtime.

Comment: For interest, I always use a *verbatim string literal* for TSQL, as that allows regular newlines *inside* the string.

Comment: @user245024, are you *sure* you want to do this because of *memory efficiency*? Or is it rather the case that you want to do it because other people told you it’s a good idea, and some of them mentioned memory efficiency? The truth is, it *is* a good idea, but for other reasons; the top #1 reason being internationalisability, my personal #2 reason being readability of the code... Memory efficiency does not factor in it because it makes no difference.

Answer (score 5):

From comments:

> it's much more efficient memory wise

No, it isn't. It is *about* the same, with `string.Format` *marginally* ***less*** efficient, as the data is passed in an array (usually GEN0), and it is necessary to parse the format string (which is actually very fast, to be fair).

It is *defined in the spec* that a composite string `+` sequence, i.e.

```
string s = "abc" + x + "def" + y;
```

Is compiled as:

```
string s = string.Concat("abc", x, "def", y);
```

Internally, this is very efficient, and doesn't do the classic "telescoping strings" problem. Additionally, there are overloads of `string.Format` taking various numbers of operands, to avoid even the params-array overhead. And additional overloads for when all operands are strings (which it can so even easier).

In short, this is costing you nothing. Unless you are doing this so you can supply the formats externally (quite common in an i18n scenario), I would leave it alone. All you are doing is risking bugs; you aren't making it more efficient.

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question? This doesn’t even *attempt* to answer the question...

Comment: @Timwi please see where (commments) I asked the OP ***why*** they wanted to do this; their answer: memory efficiency. The point is that the ***entire question*** is based ona false premise. If the purpose is to increase memory eficiency, "answering" this question ***will not help the OP***. my aim is always to help the OP with their problem.

Comment: @Marc: I see your point. However, the question is not based on a false premise: the premise is that using `string.Format` is a good idea, which it is. The fact that the OP thought it’s because of memory efficiency is of course misguided, but that doesn’t mean he’s doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @Timwi changing large swathes of code without a very clear understanding of why you are doing it is *always* a bad thing, and serves no purpose other than to introduce potential bugs. A re the "false premise"; the OPs premise *was* wrong. You are citing a different premise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Resharper code cleanup? You can create a separate profile which only makes the changes you want.